# MUI - How to see the documentation for v4?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I have `@material-ui/icons` in my project

I want to see the source code of this.

I went to `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons`

and there I click on `https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui` and go into packages I don't see `@material-ui/icons`

How to find the source code of a particular package in have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@material-ui/icons` is v4 package, you need to go to `v4.x` branch: [link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/v4.x/packages/material-ui-icons). The master branch points the the latest version (v5), which is changed to `@mui/icons-material`  so the old name doesn't exist anymore.

About documentation, you can see the docs of the next, current and previous versions [here](https://mui.com/versions/).